# No module named 'System'

Tags: python-3.x, python.net

I have an issue that has been discussed in some GitHub blogs but the answers there are so confusing and complex that I thought to ask here as well.
Before asking, let me just say I'm not an expert programmer, so my apologizes if mine is a simple question.

- I recently had to install Python 3.7
- I used to have modules like clr and System working totally fine and now everything seems broker.
  I use Anaconda/Spyder to simply load the packages clr and System and Python gives me the following error messages:

  No module named 'clr'
  No module named 'System'

I managed to fix (apparently) the clr issue by running

```
pip install clr
```

from Anaconda Prompt.
However, in order to fix the issue with the System module, it seems I need to install pythonnet (I don't knoww exactly what it is but I guess it doesn't matter).
Based on anaconda official website: https://anaconda.org/pythonnet/pythonnet I should simply run:

```
conda install -c pythonnet pythonnet
```

But that doesn't work.
My extremely limited understanding is that something is going wrong between Pythonnet and Python 3.7.
Does anybody have a clue of what I should do?

Comment: Have you tried running `pip install pythonnet` from Anaconda Prompt?

Comment: That actually did the trick. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

you must uninstall first clr and then do pip install pythonnet. pythonnet has clr and System.

check documentation: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet

Comment: worked for me. Couldn't find how to "pip install system"... and this did it. Thanks! (note: didn't need to install clr after that)

Answer (score 1):

you should use this:

```
import clr

clr.AddReference('System')

from System import String
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

What eventually worked for me, after messing around with my packages, was to: 1. uninstall clr. 2. Uninstall pythonnet. 3. Only at this point, I had to reinstall pythonnet. This sequence fixed my problem.

```
pip uninstall clr
pip uninstall pythonnet 
pip install pythonnet
```

Answer (score -1):

In my Python3, System is not a module - it's a method of the os module.

so I use

```
from os import system
```

then

```
system("<<Put Your Command Here>>")
```

If you want it called System with a capital S (maybe for backward compatability with already-written programs?), use

```
from os import system as System
```

Comment: Or you can preserve the name space (which I mostly prefer) and do `import os` and type `os.system(...)`

Comment: But that loads the whole of the os module, which is a right waste of memory if only the system method is required. AND even worse, namespace is consumed for everything named within a module, and there could be thousands! So "import os" uses MUCH more namespace than "from os import system"

Comment: This answer is not about the question posted. The OP asked about the Windows System DLL to be loaded by pythonnet, not the Python `os.system method.`