# Pythonnet no module named System

Tags: python, python.net

Trying to pass a python callback to a C# DLL. Getting `Unresolved reference System` I am using Pythonnet 2.5.2 on Python 3.7.6 for Win32.

My imports are:

```
import clr
from System import Action    #Fail Here - Unresolved reference System !
import wx
import wx.lib.filebrowsebutton as filebrowse
import os
import serial
import threading
import time
import configparser
```

I have tried [No module named 'System'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62394857/no-module-named-system).

What is the problem? How can I continue?

Comment: Maybe more than one python installed? Problem with environment variables PYTHONPATH or PYTHONHOME? Does `import sys` `print(sys.version)` give the expected Python 3.7.6?

Answer (score 0):

```
clr.AddReference('System') #add this line before import system
```